# Powershell cannot see Windows\system32\inetsrv\Config *.config files

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if you know why my inetsrv / config files are visible in explorer and command prompt but not powershell.

In cmd, if I enter dir, I can see:
- administration.config
- applicationHost.config
- redirection.confg

In posh if I enter dir, I can see none of these.

[image: files visible in CMD but not Posh]

---

Update:
@Brad @Matt - Yes thanks I've tried -Force to no avail. It certainly looks environmental. A test against another machine shows these files to be completely visible and the path to exist in a Powershell session. Also note that this problem has only started presenting recently.
Another (working server_
[image: Another Server]

My machine (still can't see files)
[image: My Machine]

Environement:
Win 8.1
IIS v8.5
Powershell v4.0
VS2013
VS2015 (recently installed)

Comment: Works on my Machine (tm). You play with you ps setings?

Comment: The answer is in the attributes. Use `-Force`. `Dir` is `Get-ChildItem` in PowerShell

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions. See update above

Comment: Is cmd.exe running as Administrator too?

Comment: I have found that running in the (x86) version sometimes causes this issue. Using the “regular” (Non x86) version populates the config files as it should.

Answer (score 0):

While is might seem that `dir` in both cases is the same but *shocker* there is a slight difference.

Using `get-alias dir` you will see that it is for `Get-ChildItem`. Run the following and you will get what you are looking for:

```
dir -Force
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem -Force
```

The reason why comes from [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx):

> **-Force**
>
> Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise not be accessed by the user, such as **hidden or system files.**

I can easily this if my hunch is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea / shot in the dark:

Try running [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx).

Set the filter to something like "Path contains inetsrv".

Do the dir command in PowerShell and in cmd.exe, and look at the paths in Process Monitor. Are they the same?

I'm wondering if you have a "VirtualStore" folder. These magic folders get created when you try to write to a system folder as a non-Administrator.